# Django rest framework + simple JWT - permission classes always enabled

Tags: django, django-views, django-rest-framework-simplejwt

I'm using [simple JWT](https://github.com/SimpleJWT/django-rest-framework-simplejwt) for authentication in my rest API.

In my function based views, I use `@permission_classes([IsAuthenticated])` to define that the JWT token is required to access that view.

However, I have some views that are not supposed to require the authentication token, therefore I didn't insert the `@permission_classes([IsAuthenticated])`, but when I test the view it still requires the token.

Here's an example:

```
@api_view(['POST'])
def userCreate(request):
    serializer = UserSerializer(data=request.data)
    if serializer.is_valid():
        serializer.save()
        return Response(status=201)
    
    return Response(serializer.errors, status=400)
```

When I try to access this view the server replies with a **401** and says:

```
{
    "detail": "Authorization header must contain two space-delimited values",
    "code": "bad_authorization_header"
}
```

In my **settings.py** file I set:

```
...
REST_FRAMEWORK = {
    'DEFAULT_AUTHENTICATION_CLASSES': [
        'rest_framework_simplejwt.authentication.JWTAuthentication',
    ],
    'DEFAULT_PAGINATION_CLASS': 'rest_framework.pagination.PageNumberPagination',
    'PAGE_SIZE': 10
}
```

Comment: Hello, 
Facing the same problem at the moment, have you found a way to make this work ? Accepted answer below with decorator doesn't work. 
Thanks a lot

Answer (score -5, accepted):

you can use allow any in the function where you want any user to access that view

`from rest_framework.permissions import AllowAny`

`@permission_classes([AllowAny])`

Answer (score 1):

I have faced a similar problem when using simple JWT. As I understand Django's permission classes only effect it's standart authentication classes.

Setting the default authentication classes to JWTAuthentication as you did in setting.py file makes every view require a JWT. So you can only disable JWT authentication for a view by setting its `authentication_classes` to an empty list. You can do so by:

Function based views:

```
@api_view(['POST'])
@authentication_classes([])
def MyFunctionView():
...
```

Class based views:

```
class MyClassView(APIView):
    authentication_classes = []
```

This way you remove the authentication requirement from a view completely rather than allowing certain types of users but it serves the same purpose for this case.